# Any need for constexpr in tag values?

Tags: c++14

[Tag dispatching](https://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching)
is used to:

> dispatch based on properties of a type

Is there any reason to make tag values `constexpr` or even
`const`?

There are code samples demonstrated both `constexpr` and
non-const tag values.  For example,
the `selector` tag value in [wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Tag_Dispatching)
is not declared a constexpr.  OTOH, [in the c++
standard](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cplusplus/draft/master/papers/n4800.pdf),
`section 31.4.4 Locks` declares several tag variables as
`constexpr`.  One example is:

```cpp
namespace std {
  struct defer_lock_t {};
  ...
  inline constexpr defer_lock_t defer_lock {};
  ...
}
```

But why is there any need for defer_lock to be a
`constexpr`?  Doesn't the following demo code:

```cpp
  struct tag_t { constexpr tag_t(){} };
  tag_t tag_nc; //tag_nonconst
  constexpr tag_t tag_ce; //tag_constexpr
//#define F_VL
#ifdef F_VL
  template<typename T>
  constexpr int f(T){ return -1;}
  constexpr int result_vl=f(tag_t{});
#endif
#define F_CN
#ifdef F_CN
  template<typename T>
  constexpr int f(T const&){ return 1;}
  constexpr int result_ce=f(tag_ce);
#endif
#define F_NC
#ifdef F_NC
  template<typename T>
  constexpr int f(T&){ return 0;}
  constexpr int result_nc=f(tag_nc);
#endif


  #include <iostream>
  int main()
  {
  #ifdef F_VL
    std::cout<<"result_vl="<<result_vl<<"\n";
  #endif
  #ifdef F_CN
    std::cout<<"result_ce="<<result_ce<<"\n";
  #endif
  #ifdef F_NC
    std::cout<<"result_nc="<<result_nc<<"\n";
  #endif
    return 0;
  }
```

if compiled without error, demonstrate that a tag value,
such as `tag_nc` in the demo code, does not need to be
declared as a `constexpr` or even a `const` value to be
usable in a `constexpr` expression, such as the `f(tag_nc)`
in the demo code?

Furthermore, if an existing tag type, such as the above
std::defer_lock_t, had `constexpr` CTOR's, and the existing
tag value were changed to non-const, then would there be any
need to change any existing user-code? I would guess it's
highly unlikely since (using symbols from the demo code):

1. a `tag_type&` actual argument is implicitly converted
    to a `const tag_type&` in any function taking a `const
    tag_type&` formal argument.
2. the **only** intention of a tag type is to:

```cpp
       dispatch based on properties of a type
```

```
 and as such, the only user-code using such a type with
 that intention would be overloads of one of these
 possible forms:
```

```cpp
       f(tag_t, ...);
       f(tag_t&, ...);
       f(tag_t const&, ...);
```

```
 and all of those possible overloads would compile and
 produce the **same** results when called with:
```

```cpp
       f(tag_nc, ...):
```

```
 where `tag_nc` was declared just as in the demo code.
```

Hence, isn't:

```cpp
  constexpr tag_t tag;
```

where `tag_t` is from the demo code, overspecifying the tag
value, `tag`?

Answer (score 0):

The `constexpr` annotation indicates 1) that the compiler should treat it as a literal, and 2) that it can be used in other constexpr code. This means that the compiler doesn't *have* to actually store it in a global variable. It can treat it as though it were a literal.

Namespace-level variables and static class variables can only be used in a `constexpr` context if they themselves are constexpr, the exception being classes and structs that are entirely empty:

```
//This compiles because A is stateless
struct A {};
A a_global; 
constexpr auto a_cexpr = a_global; 

//But this doesn't
struct B { char val; };
B b_global;
constexpr auto b_cexpr = b_global; //Error: the value 'b_global' not usable in a constant expression
```

If your tag types contained any internal state (such as a magic number or a bitmask used by the implementation), then you wouldn't be able to use it in a constant expression without declaring them constexpr.

`constexpr` is the standard way of declaring literals and constants in C++. It guarantees a lack of mutable state

**Addressing `static`:** `static`, when used in a global context, is depreciated. Originally `static` meant that a definition was only available in a single translation unit, however this functionality has been replaced by anonymous namespaces.

Comment: 1. The demo code, AFAICT,  shows that it *can* be used in a `constexpr` function.  2. Have you actual code showing tag_nc **is** stored and not treated as a literal?

Comment: Answering my 2. question, the code here https://godbolt.org/z/OFad-E shows that constexpr *is* required to avoid storing in a global variable.  Thanks for that answer :)

Comment: However, this post, http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2019-February/061163.html shows that by simply adding a static qualifier, the global variable is not created.

Comment: I updated your answer clarifying stuff

Comment: Thanks for the '//This compiles because A is stateless' answer.  I've tried to find in the [expr.const] section of the standard where it says this, but failed to find it.  It may be implied somewhere, but I could not see where.  Could you let me know where I could find in the standard where it says that a non-const variable of stateless type is usable in a constexpr?